# Where does Postfix store attachment inside email?

Tags: postfix

I am trying to find the folder where Postfix store email's attachment but I can't seems to find it. Anyone know how?

Comment: postfix doesn't store attachments separately, they are embedded in the mail.

Comment: Is there any way to extract the attachment and save the file outside?

Comment: from postfix while it's still in the queue? no, not without a lot of stuffing around.  from your mail client (e.g. `mutt` or `mail` or any script that can read your mailbox): yes, easily.

Comment: Postfix does not really care about attachments. It generally sees the header with addresses, and the messsage body with whatever it may contain, text, images, files, it's just stored as text.

Answer (score 2):

it's also inside the file that stores the mail itself and is MIME-encoded.

Comment: Is there any way to extract the attachment and save the file outside?

Comment: @Norman http://superuser.com/questions/187106/extract-save-a-mail-attachment-using-bash munpack

Comment: @JacobEvans I tried using mumpack and ripmime and think that ripmime is more straight forward due to the file structure that is extracted from the email. I could easily manipulate the files after extraction. Thanks!